# What can impact the throughput rate at tcp or Os level?

Tags: linux, tcp

I am facing a problem, where running the same application on different servers, yields unexpected performance results. For example, running the application on a particular faster server (faster cpu, more memory), with no load, yields slower performance than running on a less powerful server on the same network.

I am suspecting that either OS or TCP is causing the slowness on the faster server. I cannot use IPerf , unless i modify it, because the "performance" in my application is defined as
Component A sends a message to Component B. Component B sends an ACK to component A and ONLY then Component A would send the next message. So it is different from what IPerf does, which to my knowledge, simply tries to push as many messages as possible.

Is there a tool that can look at OS and TCP configuration and suggest the cause of slowness?

Answer (score 1):

With a "ping-pong" type of protocol like that, I think I would start by looking at latency between the two endpoints.  If you can only have a single message in-flight, small changes in latency can have pretty large impact on total throughput.

I don't know of a particular tool that I would use to benchmark the particular sort of behavior that you have.  A packet capture, as always, might be illuminating.